# Find centers of chords of quadratic form

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, analytic-geometry, quadratic-forms

Prove that the centers of chords of quadratic form $$f(x,y) = A x^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0$$ that are parellels to a line $\frac{x}{\xi}=\frac{y}{\eta}$ lies on $$ \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \right) \xi + \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right) \eta = 0$$

Comment: [How to ask a homework question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question)

Comment: Thank you, but it's not a homework question

Comment: In that case, have a look at [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Bare problem statements such as this one with no context/motivation or any of your own attempts at a solution are usually received poorly here. There’s a pretty good chance that, as it stands, this question will be closed.

Comment: Have you heard about the classical theory of **conjugate diameters** (dating back to Appolonius) ? See for example https://www.futurelearn.com/courses/maths-linear-quadratic-relations/0/steps/12110

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting apart the exceptional case $\eta=0$ (which can easily be treated separately), we can set

$$a=\dfrac{\xi}{\eta}.$$

Therefore, we have a reference straight line $y=ax$.

All straight line parallel to it have equations

$$y=ax+b \ (1a) \ \ \ \ \iff \ \ \ \ x=\dfrac{y-b}{a} \ (1b)\tag{1a/1b}$$

The intersections of conic curve

$$f(x,y) = A x^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0 \tag{2}$$

are given

- for the abscissas, by the solutions of quadratic equation in variable $x$ obtained by substituting $f(x,ax+b)=0$ (using (1a)). But in fact, we do not need to obtain the abscissas themselves, but their half sum, which is easy on a quadratic $ux^2+vx+w=0$ (it is equal to $-\dfrac{v}{2u}$). All computations done, we obtain, for the current abscissas of midpoints :

$$x_m=\dfrac{-(B+2Ca)b - (D+Ea)}{2(A+Ba+Ca^2)}\tag{3}$$

- for the ordinates, same work, but with substitution (1b) :
  $f(\dfrac{y-b}{a},y)=0$ giving this time a quadratic in $y$, out of which one obtains the current ordinate of the midpoint :

$$y_m=\dfrac{ (2A+Ba)b - (D + Ea)a}{2(A+Ba+Ca^2)}\tag{4}$$

One can already see that

$$x_m=pb+q, \ \ \ y_m=rb+s\tag{5}$$

for certain constants $p,q,r,s$, proving that the locus is (part of) a line. 
(Remember that $a$ is fixed and $b$ is variable).

From there, it shouldn't be difficult to prove that (once we have divided  by $\eta$ the given relationship with partial derivatives) that (5) verifies :

$$(2Ax_m+By_m+D)+(Bx_m+2Cy_m+E)a=0$$

(indeed the partial derivatives have to be computed in $(x_m,y_m)$).

Remark : as I already said, there is a whole classical theory behind this, the theory of conjugate diameters (dating back to Appolonius). See [for example](https://www.futurelearn.com/courses/maths-linear-quadratic-relations/0/steps/12110).

**Important edit :** Some hours later, I realized that the calculations above can be enormously shortened by considering that the property of the midpoints to be established is **invariant by translation and rotation**. Therefore, we can work with reduced equations, distinguishing :

$$x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2=1 \ \text{(ellipse)}, \ \ x^2/a^2-y^2/b^2=1 \ \text{(hyperbola)}, \ \ y^2-2px=0 \ \text{(parabola)}.$$

Comment: Thank you! I thought about above and invented another proof:
So, for example take a hyperbola in canonical form as a special case of the quadratic form. It is trivial to prove that a diameter lies on x = 0. Next, as we apply projective transformation to the hyperbola through a linear operator we get another conic section. But linear transformation save a relation between points

Comment: If you have reduced the conic for example to the case of the hyperbola in canonical form, I would say that you have exhausted all your degrees of freedom ; I mean by that that you cannot assume that the general diameter is $x=0$. But maybe, I haven't well understood what you were meaning...

Comment: Prove based on symmetry:
By definition, diameter pass though the center $(x_{m}, y_{m})$ of parallel chord family. A chord intersects quadric at two points which defines though the relations: $\frac{x - x_{m}}{\xi} = \frac{y - y_{m}}{\eta} = t$ and $\frac{x - x_{m}}{\ xi} = \frac{y - y_{m}}{\eta} = -t$  <=> $x = x_{m} + \xi t, y = y_{m} + \eta t$ and  $x = x_{m} - \xi t, y = y_{m} - \eta t$. Next, makes a substitution at $f(x, y)$. We get $f(x_{m} + \xi t, y_{m} + \eta t)$ and $f(x_{m} - \xi t, y_{m} - \eta t)$. Open brackets and 
find the difference. We will get the origin statement

Comment: I agree ; I hadn't well understood what you meant.

Comment: Thanks for your help!)

Comment: Very pleased we have had a dialog. Don't hesitate if you have other questions of this kind.